# Sort date in dd/mm/yyyy format in html table using jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, date

I have an HTML table and one column is date values.How to sort the values in descending order in the first click and in ascending order in the second click while clicking on column heading Date

```js
function getVal(elm, n) {
  var v = $(elm).find('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
  var num = v.split(/ /)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
  num = parseFloat(num);
  if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
    v = parseInt(num, 10);
  }
  return v;
}

var f = 1;
$(".table-sortable .column-head").find('span,img').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  table = $(this).closest('table');
  th = $(this).parent();
  $(th).find('span,img').toggleClass('rotate');

  f *= -1;
  var n = th.prevAll().length;
  console.log(n);
  var rows = table.find('tbody  tr').get();
  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var A = getVal(a, n);
    var B = getVal(b, n);
    if (A < B) {
      return -1 * f;
    }
    if (A > B) {
      return 1 * f;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    table.children('tbody').append(row);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>Date</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">20/01/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">20/02/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">10/01/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">08/01/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">12/04/2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">12/03/2013</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bb4659av/

Comment: Note that the date format is different in the duplicate, but as it splits it in to an array, you just need to access the different date parts to build the valid `Date()` object for comparison.

Comment: I already saw it.But in my question when two dates with same month and year comes value with different day value it not get sorted

Comment: Any way to help

Comment: In which case you've not applied the logic correctly. To solve that you should start a new question and include that code. Remember, we're here to help you debug code, not to write code for you

Comment: I have edited code in the same question.Because only after one day I can ask new question.And also included jquery code which I  have tried

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. I've re-opened it for you

Comment: You can create a `Date` with the value in the `td` and then using `valueOf` to sort the dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date in `YYYY/MM/DD` format and then sort it using `localeCompare`.

```js
function getVal(elm, n) {
  var v = $(elm).find('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
  v = v.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$3/$2/$1');
  return v;
}

var f = 1;
$(".table-sortable .column-head").find('span,img').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  table = $(this).closest('table');
  th = $(this).parent();
  $(th).find('span,img').toggleClass('rotate');

  f *= -1;
  var n = th.prevAll().length;
  var rows = table.find('tbody  tr').get();
  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var A = getVal(a, n);
    var B = getVal(b, n);
    return f * A.localeCompare(B);
  });
  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    table.children('tbody').append(row);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>Date</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">20/01/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">20/02/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">10/01/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">08/01/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">12/04/2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-values">12/03/2013</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Maria if it worked for you. Then please do mark it as the answer so it can guide others also.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a comparison, here's a version using POJS once you have a cell in the column to sort. I think it will be a lot more efficient that the jQuery alternative.

"Ascending order" is ambiguous to me, I guess you want the newest dates at the top. To reverse the order, just reverse the comparison in the sort function.

```js
/* Given a table cell, find the parent table and sort the first tbody's
** rows by the given column as dates in format dd/mm/yyyy. Sorts most
** recent date to top, oldest to bottom.
*/
function sortAsDate(cell) {
  var col = cell.cellIndex,
      table = cell.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode,
      tbody = table.tBodies[0],
      formatter = row => row.cells[col].textContent.split(/\D/).reverse().join('');

  Array.from(tbody.rows)
       .sort((a, b) => formatter(a).localeCompare(formatter(b)))
       .reduceRight((acc, row) => tbody.appendChild(row), null);
}
```

```html
<table class="table-sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span onclick="sortAsDate(this.parentNode)">Date</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="table-row"><td class="column-values">20/01/2015</td></tr>
    <tr class="table-row"><td class="column-values">20/02/2016</td></tr>
    <tr class="table-row"><td class="column-values">10/01/2017</td></tr>
    <tr class="table-row"><td class="column-values">08/01/2017</td></tr>
    <tr class="table-row"><td class="column-values">12/04/2013</td></tr>
    <tr class="table-row"><td class="column-values">12/03/2013</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```